# Creating a hierarchical list of all categories in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have been trying to figure this out, but am getting lost in the possible option. I have a set of categories in my Wordpress, up to 3 levels deep. I would like to generate a list of links to each category, keeping the hierarchy in order. The format I'm after would be something like this:

```
Parent
-Child Level 1
-Child level 1
--Child level 2
-Child level 1
Parent
-Child level 1
--Child level 2
```

I have figured out how to alter the query to always return empty categories etc, but I just can't get the format right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code, I can not help you much, but [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function should do exactly what you want by default.

Note that, to indent the lists correctly, you will need to [add some CSS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Lists_with_CSS), instead.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, you are completely right. I just got too carried away with the options and extra examples in the codex. Thanks!